# Solving integrodifferential equation using dsolve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, dsolve

I have following integro-differential equation:
[image]

I tried to solve it using symbolic math toolbox in Matlab:

```
syms x(t)
Dx = diff(x,t)
cond = x(0)==1
eqn = Dx + 2*x + 2*int(x) == 0
x(t) = dsolve(eqn, cond)
```

dsolve gives:

```
x(t) =
 
exp(1 - (2*t + 2)^2/4)
```

Matlab solution is wrong.

Solving equation by hand using Laplace transform I get:
[image]

Why Matlab gives the wrong symbolic solution?
Thank you.